# UDP Send Matlab

Tags: matlab, udp, send

So I want to send a double (47.268) via a UDP Pack. I have got it running in simulink and can receive the data however i am trying to code it so that it executes in a script. The code below should work however i am receiving no data on the IP address i am sending to and have no idea why. My code is below

```
UDPComOut=udp('deviceIP','LocalPort',25001);
fopen(UDPComOut)
fwrite(UDPComOut, 47.628, 'double')
fclose(UDPComOut)
```

Anyone know where im going wrong any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did u try with localhost?

Comment: I tried  it, didn't work

Comment: Yea i realized the other one was because of the echo. I figured that out. I'm just using the exact same concept for writing but somehow its different fwrite(obj,A,'precision') is the layout, where A is the only difference, but still it doesnt even send a packet of data to the device.

Comment: Figured it out. For some reason you have to remove 'LocalPort' from the UDP